# quick question: How to use Move_Base package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how do I incorporate Move_Base package onto my robot?
I am running this in gazebo, is it all I have to do is to run the package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63962/quick-question:-how-to-use-move_base-package?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start by reading [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base). And by going through the [navigation tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation).

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0